# Bootstrap file is not being accessed in php file

Tags: css, path

My bootstrap css file is located at

> C:\Users\SCEA\Downloads\bootstrap-3.3.7\css

and for linking this to my php file I have given absolute path as:

```
<link href="C:\Users\SCEA\Downloads\bootstrap-3.3.7\css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but the effect of css is not visible.Is my css file not getting linked?

Answer (score 0):

You might have a typo before `css`. The backslash before it might need to be a period.

```
<link href="C:\Users\SCEA\Downloads\bootstrap-3.3.7.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

If are running server in your local computer I suggest moving this file within the server document root.

Comment: `css` is a folder inside `bootstrap-3.3.7`

Answer (score 0):

Your comment:

> css is a folder inside bootstrap-3.3.7

Probably in the CSS folder are the actual css files.
You need to refer to the actual CSS files and not to the folder itself.

Here is a quickfix using CDN:

Put these links in and it works guaranteed